# Assign array value inside object initializer in c#

Tags: c#, object-initializers

I have a class as below.

```
public class PurgeRecord
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public int PurgeFileID { get; set; }
    public string AuthorisationID { get; set; }
    public string RecordSystem { get; set; }
    public string KeyName { get; set; }
    public string[] KeyValues { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public string ErrorDetail { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting some string values separated by '|' into string array and lopping over it as follows.

```
string[] test = Convert.ToString(values[5]).Split('|');
foreach (string key in test)
{
    purgeRecord = new PurgeRecord()
    {
        KeyValues = key,
        IsValid = true,
        FileName = "XYZ"
    };
    lstPurgeRecords.Add(purgeRecord);
}
```

But I am getting an error on key as cannot convert string to string[] implicitly. I tried many ways and tried googling as well but no luck.

Please help.

Comment: If `key` is a name then assign it to `KeyName` property

Comment: The problem isn't only with the code, the problem is that we don't understand what you're trying to do. Why did you try placing a string value into an array variable? What was the expected outcome?

Comment: KeyValues is of string[] datatype and you are assigning that to a string value  key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `KeyValues` property type is `string` array, when you are trying to initialize a `PurgeRecord` instance you are trying to insert a `string` into a `string[]`.

So this is what you should do:

```
//Every object instance in C# have the function 'ToString'.
string[] test = values[5].ToString().Split('|');

foreach (string key in test)
{
    purgeRecord = new PurgeRecord()
    {
        //Create an array to insert in the values, but probably this is the KeyName
        KeyValues = new[] { key },
        IsValid = true,
        FileName = "XYZ"
    };
    lstPurgeRecords.Add(purgeRecord);
}
```

There is a nice way to do with `Linq` too:

```
lstPurgeRecords = values[ 5 ]
                    .ToString()
                    .Split( '|' )
                    .Select( key => new PurgeRecord 
                    {
                        KeyValues = new[] { key },
                        IsValid = true,
                        FileName = "XYZ"
                    } );
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split` itself returns `String[]`

> Splits a string into substrings that are based on the characters in an array.

Its **Syntax**

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

Simply update your code

from

```
string[] test = Convert.ToString(values[5]).Split('|');
```

with

```
string[] test = values[5]).Split('|');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put it inside a `string[]` like this:

```
KeyValues = new string[] { key }
```

Or even shorter format:

```
KeyValues = new [] { key }
```